# Accessing post->ID outside of the loop for listing child pages

Tags: posts, php, wp-query

I'm wanting to list child pages of my current page in the sidebar of theme. However my sidebar (left side) is before the loop in the template and the post->ID won't return anything if it's before the loop.

My current code:

```
<?php

wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID); 

?>
```

I've read something about calling a global variable to access this but haven't had any luck thus far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the post->ID won't return anything if it's before the loop

Generally speaking, this is false. The `$post` variable is set well before the Loop starts in your theme, for most pages. The main query "primes" that variable to the first post in the Loop. That said, depending on this variable outside the Loop is not the most reliable approach. More reliable, would be to use [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages).

```
$qobj = get_queried_object();
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$qobj->ID);
```

Because `get_queried_object` returns different information depending on the page you are on, you are also better off checking for the page type before using it.

```
if (is_page()) {
    $qobj = get_queried_object();
    wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$qobj->ID);
}
```

Or check the object itself.

```
$qobj = get_queried_object();
if (isset($qobj->post_type) && 'page' == $qobj->post_type) {
  wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$qobj->ID);
}
```

Those are just examples. I don't know what your precise conditions are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// get the post id
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();

// get the children
$children = get_pages('child_of' => $post_id);

//output them
if( count( $children ) != 0 ) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        // if we only want children, not grandchildren
        if ($child->post_parent == $post_id) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"" . get_permalink($child->ID) . "\">";
            echo $child->post_title;
            echo "</a></li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Edited to use get_queried_object_id()

Comment: Edited again to change the reference to the $post_id variable in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

try to make code like

```
global $post;
var_dump($post);//test values in $post
wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get this code: http://pastebin.com/JKb1gcfX

Comment: var_dump() function olny for testing purpose that your are getting your $post object and so your post id.Is it Working ?

Comment: get_the_ID() works well only in WordPress loop but in my code you can get your post id outside the loop

Comment: @Ravs `get_the_ID()` is no different than calling `global $post` and `$post->ID`. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L28 and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L386

Comment: @Matthew Boynes thanks for valuable links and info.

Comment: No prob, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

There's really not enough information to give an accurate answer here, but if your suspicion is correct, try replacing `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm happy to give anymore information I'm fairly new to this kind of stuff that's why my question may be a bit specific? - I've just tried replacing $post->ID with get_the_ID() and had no luck

Comment: How about `get_queried_object_id()` ?

Comment: <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.get_queried_object_id()); ?> - this returns all pages as if there was no filter being applied

Comment: It seems like you're not on a page. Are you actually on a single page view? (rendered with page.php or an overridden page template?)

Comment: Yes, I'm on my home.php page, though I do want this to appear on every page eventually.

Comment: And is your homepage set to be a static page, or a list of recent posts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8915/discussion-between-rowefx-and-matthew-boynes)